# JSON.filter(...).then is not a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to filter a JSON (JSONauction) and (I believe there's a better way to do it, but I haven't figured out) I have this function to filter said JSON:

```js
function filterAuctions() {
    var data_filter = JSONauctions.filter(element => element.item_name == nameToSearch)
      .then(data_filter => data_filter.filter(element => element.bin == true))
      .then(data_filter => data_filter.filter(element => element.claimed == false));
    console.log(data_filter);
    return data_filter;
}
```

Like I said in the title, I get JSON.filter(...).then is not a function error. What am I doing incorrect?
Example JSON Code of JSONauctions:

```json
{
    "auctions": [{
        "uuid": "4f031cd51bc04c89b9a7f58c57263abf",
        "auctioneer": "102fdb78f23d482f81920dfab9cc2941",
        "profile_id": "5fa6443d2b5f4ad6af31380945b7d2a4",
        "coop": ["102fdb78f23d482f81920dfab9cc2941", "05b42821276a4fb69a39e43a62fe651c", "cf5e08e92e1f4cfe86fe7c82ee3dcb1e"],
        "start": 1601083888377,
        "end": 1601105488377,
        "item_name": "Unreal Runaan's Bow",
        "item_lore": "§7Damage: §c+160\n§7Strength: §c+75 §9(Unreal +25)\n§7Crit Chance: §c+13% §9(Unreal +13%)\n§7Crit Damage: §c+50% §9(Unreal +50%)\n\n§9Aiming V\n§9Cubism V\n§9Impaling III\n§9Infinite Quiver V\n§9Piercing I\n§9Power V\n§9Snipe III\n§9Telekinesis I\n\n§6Item Ability: Triple Shot\n§7Shoots 3 arrows at a time! The 2\n§7extra arrows deal §a40%\n§a§7percent of the damage.\n\n§6§lLEGENDARY BOW",
        "extra": "Unreal Runaan's Bow Bow Impaling Piercing Infinite Quiver Snipe Power Telekinesis Cubism Aiming",
        "category": "weapon",
        "tier": "LEGENDARY",
        "starting_bid": 634000,
        "item_bytes": "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",
        "claimed": false,
        "claimed_bidders": [],
        "highest_bid_amount": 0,
        "bin": true,
        "bids": []
    }, {
        "uuid": "c2cc6276429443088508ea21f485bca2",
        "auctioneer": "24101a3cb3b0439dbf61b457ef65d0fd",
        "profile_id": "24101a3cb3b0439dbf61b457ef65d0fd",
        "coop": ["24101a3cb3b0439dbf61b457ef65d0fd"],
        "start": 1601079849776,
        "end": 1601252649776,
        "item_name": "Rapid Runaan's Bow",
        "item_lore": "§7Damage: §c+160\n§7Strength: §c+60 §9(Rapid +10)\n§7Crit Damage: §c+75% §9(Rapid +75%)\n\n§9Aiming V\n§9Cubism V\n§9Impaling III\n§9Infinite Quiver V\n§9Piercing I\n§9Power V\n§9Snipe III\n§9Telekinesis I\n\n§6Item Ability: Triple Shot\n§7Shoots 3 arrows at a time! The 2\n§7extra arrows deal §a40%\n§a§7percent of the damage.\n\n§6§lLEGENDARY BOW",
        "extra": "Rapid Runaan's Bow Bow Impaling Piercing Infinite Quiver Snipe Power Telekinesis Aiming Cubism",
        "category": "weapon",
        "tier": "LEGENDARY",
        "starting_bid": 644000,
        "item_bytes": "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",
        "claimed": false,
        "claimed_bidders": [],
        "highest_bid_amount": 0,
        "bin": true,
        "bids": []
    }]
}
```

I'm happy to provide any more info if requested.

Comment: Are you trying to get an array of those objects which are of a particular `item_name` with `bin` as true and `claimed` as false?

Comment: `then` is usually used in Promise callbacks, filter is often a method of array, and that is not a Promise, so has no then.

Comment: Not sure why you are using .then function, it is a Promise concept, so you are basically trying to mix 2 very different things.

Comment: @AnujPancholi that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you've assigned `JSONauctions` to so I'm going to cover a few cases:

### First Case

Since you are using `filter()` on `JSONauctions`, one could think that the case is that it's the array `auctions` in the object that you've mentioned.

In that case, try:

```
function filterAuctions() {
    var data_filter = JSONauctions.filter(element => element.item_name === nameToSearch
        && element.bin === true
        && element.claimed === false)
    console.log(data_filter);
    return data_filter;
}
```

### Second Case

You mentioned that in the above approach you were getting the error "`JSONauctions.filter()` is not a function" which suggests that `JSONauctions` *is* the object itself, like:

```
const JSONauctions = {
    "auctions": [{
        "uuid": "4f031cd51bc04c89b9a7f58c57263abf",
        "auctioneer": "102fdb78f23d482f81920dfab9cc2941",
        "profile_id": "5fa6443d2b5f4ad6af31380945b7d2a4",
        "coop": ["102fdb78f23d482f81920dfab9cc2941", "05b42821276a4fb69a39e43a62fe651c", "cf5e08e92e1f4cfe86fe7c82ee3dcb1e"],
        "start": 1601083888377,
        "end": 1601105488377,
        "item_name": "Unreal Runaan's Bow",
        "item_lore": "§7Damage: §c+160\n§7Strength: §c+75 §9(Unreal +25)\n§7Crit Chance: §c+13% §9(Unreal +13%)\n§7Crit Damage: §c+50% §9(Unreal +50%)\n\n§9Aiming V\n§9Cubism V\n§9Impaling III\n§9Infinite Quiver V\n§9Piercing I\n§9Power V\n§9Snipe III\n§9Telekinesis I\n\n§6Item Ability: Triple Shot\n§7Shoots 3 arrows at a time! The 2\n§7extra arrows deal §a40%\n§a§7percent of the damage.\n\n§6§lLEGENDARY BOW",
        "extra": "Unreal Runaan's Bow Bow Impaling Piercing Infinite Quiver Snipe Power Telekinesis Cubism Aiming",
        "category": "weapon",
        "tier": "LEGENDARY",
        "starting_bid": 634000,
        "item_bytes": "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",
        "claimed": false,
        "claimed_bidders": [],
        "highest_bid_amount": 0,
        "bin": true,
        "bids": []
    }, {
        "uuid": "c2cc6276429443088508ea21f485bca2",
        "auctioneer": "24101a3cb3b0439dbf61b457ef65d0fd",
        "profile_id": "24101a3cb3b0439dbf61b457ef65d0fd",
        "coop": ["24101a3cb3b0439dbf61b457ef65d0fd"],
        "start": 1601079849776,
        "end": 1601252649776,
        "item_name": "Rapid Runaan's Bow",
        "item_lore": "§7Damage: §c+160\n§7Strength: §c+60 §9(Rapid +10)\n§7Crit Damage: §c+75% §9(Rapid +75%)\n\n§9Aiming V\n§9Cubism V\n§9Impaling III\n§9Infinite Quiver V\n§9Piercing I\n§9Power V\n§9Snipe III\n§9Telekinesis I\n\n§6Item Ability: Triple Shot\n§7Shoots 3 arrows at a time! The 2\n§7extra arrows deal §a40%\n§a§7percent of the damage.\n\n§6§lLEGENDARY BOW",
        "extra": "Rapid Runaan's Bow Bow Impaling Piercing Infinite Quiver Snipe Power Telekinesis Aiming Cubism",
        "category": "weapon",
        "tier": "LEGENDARY",
        "starting_bid": 644000,
        "item_bytes": "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",
        "claimed": false,
        "claimed_bidders": [],
        "highest_bid_amount": 0,
        "bin": true,
        "bids": []
    }]
}
```

In this case, as some others have pointed out in the comments, you may try:

```
function filterAuctions() {
    var data_filter = JSONauctions.auctions.filter(element => element.item_name === nameToSearch
        && element.bin === true
        && element.claimed === false)
    console.log(data_filter);
    return data_filter;
}
```

**A note about `.then()`:**

It is a [method of the `Promise` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#:%7E:text=The%20then()%20method%20returns,failure%20cases%20of%20the%20Promise%20.), and can only be used on promises. `.filter()` is an array method that returns a new array with the properties filtered as per the callback, so, running `.then()` on an array will result in an error stating something like "`.then()` is not a function", which should explain the error that you got initially.

Comment: I tried that and it threw `JSONauctions.filter is not a function`

Comment: Is `JSONauctions` assigned with the object that you've mentioned or with the `auctions` array inside it? `.filter()` is an array method and will only run on arrays. Since you're running it on `JSONauctions` and referencing properties like `item_name` that are in the objects of that array, I was assuming it was that array.

Comment: I'll add this to the main question and I'm sorry for not clarifying, JSONauctions is a variable, and the actual JSON Object is on another file, and they are linked with `var JSONauctions = require('../actualjsonfile.json');`

Comment: @DeltaCodes what if you do `JSONauctions.auctions.filter(element.....`